# Android boolean value not doing the right thing - MediaPlayer keeps playing when it shouldn't be playing

Tags: android, checkbox, menu, boolean, android-mediaplayer

I've created an app which starts with a main Activity. On that main Activity, there are 2 checkboxes (cbPlayMusic and cbPlaySound). When you start the game by clicking the start button,with this code:

```
btStart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(GobbleFishMainActivity.this, GobbleFishGame.class);
            intent.putExtra(INTENT_EXTRA_PLAY_MUSIC, cbMusic.isChecked());
            intent.putExtra(INTENT_EXTRA_PLAY_SOUND, cbSound.isChecked());


            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

On top of the activity is this:

```
public static final String INTENT_EXTRA_PLAY_MUSIC = "be.fielibert.gobblefish.extra.PLAY_MUSIC";
public static final String INTENT_EXTRA_PLAY_SOUND = "be.fielibert.gobblefish.extra.PLAY_SOUND";
```

Then when you've clicked Start, GobbleFishGame Activity, this is the onCreate code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    initBitmaps();
    mGraphView = new GraphView(this);
    mPlayMusic = getIntent().getBooleanExtra(GobbleFishMainActivity.INTENT_EXTRA_PLAY_MUSIC,true);
    mPlaySound = getIntent().getBooleanExtra(GobbleFishMainActivity.INTENT_EXTRA_PLAY_SOUND,true);

    setContentView(mGraphView);
    mGraphView.runProgram();
    playMusic();



}
```

When mPlayMusic is true, the background music starts playing when the GobbleFishGame Activity is created due to playMusic():

```
 private void playMusic(){

    if (!mPlayMusic) {
        return;
    }
    mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(GobbleFishGame.this, R.raw.song);
    mPlayer.setLooping(true);
    mPlayer.start();
}
```

Everything works fine until now. But, when you press the menu button on your Android device, a menu is created with 4 options: Main menu, Restart game, Toggle music, Toggle sound. 
This is the code for the menu:

```
 @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, MENU_MENU, Menu.NONE, "Main menu");
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, MENU_RESTART,   Menu.NONE, "Restart game");
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, MENU_MUSIC,    Menu.NONE, "Toggle music");
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, MENU_SOUND,   Menu.NONE, "Toggle sound");
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onMenuOpened(int featureId, Menu menu) {
    mGraphView.pauseGame();
    return super.onMenuOpened(featureId, menu);
}

@Override
public void onOptionsMenuClosed(Menu menu) {
    super.onOptionsMenuClosed(menu);
    if(isStopping=true){
        return;
    }
    else{
        mGraphView.continueGame();
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == MENU_MENU) {
        //mPlayer.release();
        isStopping=true;
        stopMusic();
        mGraphView.mState = STATE_STOP;
        Intent intent = new Intent(GobbleFishGame.this, GobbleFishMainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
        //finish();
    }
    else if (item.getItemId() == MENU_RESTART) {
        mGraphView.init();
        mPlayer.reset();
        playMusic();
    }
    else if (item.getItemId() == MENU_MUSIC) {
        if (!mPlayMusic) {
            mPlayMusic=true;
            if (mPlayer != null) {
                //mPlayer.start();
                playMusic();
            }
            //playMusic();
        }
        if(mPlayMusic){
            mPlayMusic=false;
            stopMusic();
        }
    }
    else if (item.getItemId() == MENU_SOUND) {
        if (!mPlaySound) {
            mPlaySound=true;
            if (mp != null) {
                mp.reset();
            }
            //mp.reset();
        }
        if(mPlaySound){
            mPlaySound=false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

However, the options Toggle music and Toggle sound won't work. This is what happens: when checkbox music is true (so the music is playing), if you then toggle music it works fine. But, if you then want to toggle music back on, it works too, but then the pause doesn't work anymore. In pause I call mPlayer.pause, and that works fine if I haven't toggled music on or off. If I have toggled music on or off, pause doesn't work anymore for some reason.

This is pause code:

```
public void pauseGame() {
        if (mMode != MODE_PAUSE) {
            mMode = MODE_PAUSE;
            if (!mPlayMusic) {

                return;
            }
            if (mPlayer != null) {

                mPlayer.pause();


            }


        }
    }
```

So that's my problem. The same problem occurs with toggle sound: if I toggle sound off, it works and there is no sound anymore (sounds like when my fish eats another fish or game over sound), but when I toggle sound on again, it doesn't work: no sound is played when it should be played.

My guess is that it has something to do with the booleans. I don't know what's wrong with my code though, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the assignment inside `if(isStopping=true) ...` in method `onOptionsMenuClosed` the intended operation?

Comment: Yes, that's because when you choose option Main menu, you go back to MainActivity, and then the music should stop playing. If I don't use isStopping, than mGraphView.continueGame(); will be called, in which the music will be continued.

Comment: What I meant is: did you mean `==` instead of `=`? Otherwise the if-condition is always fulfilled and the else-path is needless.

Comment: Isn't == and = the same thing when it comes to booleans? I'm not sure, I forgot to add that I'm a newbie with Android and Java programming, I have to make an Android-app for my final year project (and I have never seen Java before).

Comment: `==` is equals operator and `=` is assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the `MENU_MUSIC` and `MENU_SOUND` handling you have the following lines of code:

```
if (!mPlayMusic) {
    mPlayMusic=true;
    ... playMusic(); ...
}
if(mPlayMusic) {
    mPlayMusic=false;
    ... stopMusic(); ...
}
```

Since you omitted the `else` whenever the first `if` condition is true also the second one is triggered (due to the assignment `mPlayMusic=true;` inside the first) and thus the music immediately stops after starting.

Comment: You're right! I can't believe that was my mistake all the time, however I don't really know how I can fix the code so that it works how I want it to when you click toggle music: if mPlayMusic is false, then mPlayMusic must become true and the music should start playing, and if mPlayMusic is true, then mPlayMusic must become false and the music should stop playing.

Comment: @user1417942 So why can't you just put `else` in between?

Comment: Yeah, was just about to edit my last comment to say that a simple else would do the trick. I'm not really thinking straight at this moment I guess.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, now the music and sound are working as intended.